# Suppress a newline inside <pre> tags in Javadoc

Tags: java, html, javadoc

I am documenting a java method using Javadoc. On occasion I use `<pre>` tags for fromatting. Inside the `<pre>` tags I use tags like `<em>`, `<b>` etc. to format the text. Sometimes the lines get very long due to the tags that do not show later. So I would like to insert a linebreak for readability in the Javadoc that will not show later. The following example shall clarify what I am trying to do:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * 
 * <b><em>This</em></b> is <em><b>a</em></b> very <em><b>short</em></b> <em>sentence</em>
 * 
 * </pre>
 *
```

This will later show in the browser as

> ***This*** is ***a*** very ***short*** *sentence*

As you can see, the tags make the sentence very long in the editor, so I want to insert a newline in the editor to improve readability, but it shall display as one line in the browser.

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * 
 * <b><em>This</em></b> is <em><b>a</em></b> <supress this newline>
 * very <em><b>short</em></b> <em>sentence</em>
 * 
 * </pre>
```

Is there a way to suppress a newline inside `<pre>` tags? If not, can a similar result be achieved without using `<pre>` tags?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree here. `<pre>` is for code, and anything else you want formatted as-is. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP Please read the last part of the question again. I clearly stated that I am willing to use an alternative approach to achieve my goal. Simply stating 'that is not what `<pre>` is for' is not helpful in the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t really a javadoc question, it’s a general HTML question.

You can use an HTML comment:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * 
 * <b><em>This</em></b> is <em><b>a</em></b> <!--
 * -->very <em><b>short</em></b> <em>sentence</em>
 * 
 * </pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, that produced the result I was looking for.